# Advice for measuring MAUs (Monthly Active Users) through A/B testing?

Tags: experiment-design, ab-test

thanks in advance for your advice.

I'm trying to determine whether certain product feature improvements increased the number of monthly active users (active is defined as whether the user made a purchase in the last 30 days). We have the ability to A/B test but I'm getting stuck because this MAU metric is a moving window metric. If we run the experiment for exactly 30 days then I think calculating the impact to MAU is easy. But most of the time our experiments run for more or less days than 30 days. Another issue is that users enter the experiment at different times. For example, we might run an experiment from Jan 1 - Jan 30. Each day, the users that perform certain actions in the app are then entered in to the experiment and assigned to either the treatment or control group. Below are a few scenarios to illustrate my point.

Note: All scenarios are A/B tests where we split our user base into equal treatment and control groups. So far, I've been calculating "MAU Rate", which is the proportion of users who placed an order in the last 30 days as of the last day of the experiment.

Scenario 1: Run experiment for exactly 30 days. At the end of 30 days, simply compare the proportion of users in each group that placed an order.

Scenario 2: Run experiment for less than 30 days, say 14 days. At the end of the experiment, compare the proportion of users in each group that placed an order in the last 30 days as of the last day of the experiment. The issue is that this will include days from before the experiment started. If I use only the days during the experiment, then I'm not really measuring MAU since MAU is 30 days and the experiment ran for only 14 days.

Scenario 3: Run experiment for more than 30 days, say 45 days. At the end of the experiment, compare the proportion of users in each group that placed an order in the last 30 days as of the last day of the experiment. The issue is that this will exclude data from the first 15 days of the experiment. If I use all the days during the experiment, then I'm not really measuring MAU since MAU is 30 days and the experiment ran for 45 days.

Does anyone have any advice on how to measure impact to MAU through experimentation? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you use historical data to calculate a multiplier that scales X day AUs to 30 Day AUs?

Comment: Hi dimitriy. That sounds interesting but could you elaborate, I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: proxy metrics..

Answer (score 1):

Get your data into a format like this:

```
days group  n   y
1   Control 50  3
1   Treat   50  2
2   Control 50  6
2   Treat   50  5
3   Control 50  8
3   Treat   50  23
```

Here days measure how long users have been in the test, n is the sample size for that group, and y is the total count of 1+ conversions. For example, the last row has 50 treated users that have been in the test for three days, and 23 have made at least one purchase. The longer you run the test, the more rows you will have.

Fit a Poisson model of y on group as a factor with [a logarithmic offset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52364/7071) equal to n*days. This will adjust for how long users have been in the test. I would use heteroskedastic variance here.

Calculate [a finite difference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/499087/7071) for group from the Poisson model with the offset set to 30*N to get the effect of assigning everyone in your test to treatment for 30 days. N is the total number of users in the trial. This is not the only counterfactual for N that makes sense.

Here's an example in Stata:

```
. /* Parameters */
. scalar test_days         = 49

. scalar daily_inflow  = 100

. scalar frac_treat        = 2/3

. scalar p_c                       = 0.05

. scalar p_t                       = 0.10

. scalar cf_days       = 30

. scalar cf_log_offset = ln(scalar(cf_days)*scalar(daily_inflow))

. scalar true_diff         = scalar(cf_days)*scalar(daily_inflow)*(scalar(p_t) - scalar(p_c))

. /* Data */
. set obs `=scalar(test_days)'
Number of observations (_N) was 0, now 49.

. set seed 9924

. gen test_day = _n

. gen n_c          = round(scalar(daily_inflow)*(1 - scalar(frac_treat)),1)

. gen n_t          = round(scalar(daily_inflow)*scalar(frac_treat),1)

. gen y_c          = rpoisson(test_day*scalar(p_c)*n_c)

. gen y_t          = rpoisson(test_day*scalar(p_t)*n_t)

. reshape long n_ y_, i(test_day) j(group,string)
(j = c t)

Data                               Wide   ->   Long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of observations               49   ->   98          
Number of variables                   5   ->   4           
j variable (2 values)                     ->   group
xij variables:
                                n_c n_t   ->   n_
                                y_c y_t   ->   y_
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. rename (*_) *

. strrec group ("c" = 0 "Control") ("t" = 1 "Treat"), replace
group
(49 real changes made)
(49 real changes made)

. xtset group test_day

Panel variable: group (strongly balanced)
 Time variable: test_day, 1 to 49
         Delta: 1 unit

. /* Models */
. gen double log_offset = ln(n*test_day)

. constraint define 1 _b[log_offset] = 1

. 
. forvalues d = 7(7)49 {
  2.         di "Model for `d' Days"
  3.         qui poisson y i.group c.log_offset if test_day <= `d', vce(robust) constraint(1) nolog
  4.         margins, dydx(group) at(log_offset == `=ln(scalar(cf_days)*scalar(daily_inflow))') post
  5.         eststo D`d', title("`d' Days")
  6. }
Model for 7 Days

Conditional marginal effects                                Number of obs = 14
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Predicted number of events, predict()
dy/dx wrt:  1.group
At: log_offset = 8.006368

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
      Treat  |   168.8312   31.84171     5.30   0.000     106.4226    231.2398
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
Model for 14 Days

Conditional marginal effects                                Number of obs = 28
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Predicted number of events, predict()
dy/dx wrt:  1.group
At: log_offset = 8.006368

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
      Treat  |   174.7238   17.81522     9.81   0.000     139.8066     209.641
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
Model for 21 Days

Conditional marginal effects                                Number of obs = 42
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Predicted number of events, predict()
dy/dx wrt:  1.group
At: log_offset = 8.006368

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
      Treat  |   179.9386    10.7771    16.70   0.000     158.8158    201.0613
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
Model for 28 Days

Conditional marginal effects                                Number of obs = 56
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Predicted number of events, predict()
dy/dx wrt:  1.group
At: log_offset = 8.006368

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
      Treat  |   154.2434   9.179377    16.80   0.000     136.2521    172.2346
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
Model for 35 Days

Conditional marginal effects                                Number of obs = 70
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Predicted number of events, predict()
dy/dx wrt:  1.group
At: log_offset = 8.006368

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
      Treat  |   148.5322   7.057732    21.05   0.000     134.6993    162.3651
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
Model for 42 Days

Conditional marginal effects                                Number of obs = 84
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Predicted number of events, predict()
dy/dx wrt:  1.group
At: log_offset = 8.006368

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
      Treat  |   148.9622   5.317085    28.02   0.000     138.5409    159.3835
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
Model for 49 Days

Conditional marginal effects                                Number of obs = 98
Model VCE: Robust

Expression: Predicted number of events, predict()
dy/dx wrt:  1.group
At: log_offset = 8.006368

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       group |
      Treat  |   151.9719   4.731076    32.12   0.000     142.6991    161.2446
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.

. coefplot D*, pstyle(p1) xline(`=scalar(true_diff)') xlab(#15) ylab(none) title("Change in D`=scalar(cf_days)' Conversions Using D* Model") xtitle("D`=scalar(cf_days)' C
> onversions") asequation eqstrict legend(off)
```

This code fits a sequence of models using 1-7 weeks of rolling test data using simulated data. Here's the graph of the total effect. :
[image]

This compares the number of conversions in 30 days if 100 users received treatment versus if they all were assigned to the control experience. The vertical line is the simulated truth. The model is able to extrapolate to 30 days fairly well using fewer than 4 weeks of data.